# L1 и L2 регуляризация, L1 и L2 норма

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Что общего в этих понятиях и чем они различаются?

Правильно ли я понимаю, что при L1 регуляризации, часть признаков совсем отбрасывается, а при L2 регуляризации признаки сглаживаются, чтобы из-за одного признака не "затухали" остальные? А L1 и L2 норма, это просто разные варианты для того что бы расчитывать расстояние?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Норма** — функционал, заданный на векторном пространстве и обобщающий понятие длины вектора или абсолютного значения числа.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0_(%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0))

Общая формула для **L<sub>p</sub> norm**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**L<sub>1</sub> norm** / [Расстояние городских кварталов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**L<sub>2</sub> norm** / [Евклидова метрика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Для регуляризации к формуле ошибки добавляется соответствующая норма - при **L<sub>1</sub> regularization** добавляется **L<sub>1</sub> norm** и **L<sub>2</sub> norm** в случае **L<sub>2</sub> regularization**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]